# how to make or set a user details as a Auth::User() details Manually

Tags: laravel

Advance Thanks You for this replay...

Initially i was check whether is there is any Auth::User() available if yes continue to process that details for another some process ... else no(I  meant that there is no Auth::User() ) i was initiated to maintain the dummy user details which is the dummy user details was already available on my user table.... hoe to switch that when there is no Auth::User() i wanna to set the dummy user details as a Auth::User() collectio how to do that.....

I don't have an idea i was tried

$authUser = Auth::user();

```
        if($authUser == null){
            $dummyUser = User::where('email','dummy@dummy.com')->first();
            if(!$dummyUser){
                $dummyUser = new User();
                $dummyUser -> name = "dummy";
                $dummyUser -> email = "dummy@dummy.com";
                $dummyUser -> password = bcrypt("dummy");
                $dummyUser -> save();
            }

            if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$dummyUser->email,'password'=>'dummy'])){
                dd('Auth User');
            }else{
                dd('Credential mismatch');
            }

            $authUser = $dummyUser;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
if(!Auth::check()){
            $dummyUser = User::where('email','dummy@dummy.com')->first();
            if(!$dummyUser){
                $dummyUser = new User();
                $dummyUser -> name = "dummy";
                $dummyUser -> email = "dummy@dummy.com";
                $dummyUser -> password = bcrypt("dummy");
                $dummyUser -> save();
            }

            if(Auth::attempt(['email'=>$dummyUser->email,'password'=>'dummy'])){
                dd('Auth User');
            }else{
                dd('Credential mismatch');
            }

            $authUser = $dummyUser;
        }
```